# Is Seifert-Weber space homogeneous for a Lie group?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, geometric-topology, homogeneous-spaces

Siefert-Weber space is a compact connected hyperbolic 3 manifold without boundary (closed hyperbolic 3 manifold). It can be constructed by gluing faces of a dodecahedron.

The other two consistent ways of gluing the faces of the dodecahedron yield $ \mathbb{RP}^3 $ and the Poincare homology sphere, both of which are spherical 3 manifolds admitting a transitive action by the group of rotations of 3 space $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $.

Is something similar true for Siefert-Weber space? Does there exist a Lie group $ G $ and a closed subgroup $ H $ such that $ G/H $ is Siefert-Weber space?

Please note: I am already aware that hyperbolic 3 space $ \mathbb{H}^3 $  is a homogeneous space. There are lots of essentially equivalent ways of doing this that all involve taking a 6 dimensional Lie group $ G $ that is essentially the isometries of  $ \mathbb{H}^3 $ and moding out by a maximal compact subgroup $ K $ to get a contractible 3 manifold with constant sectional curvature -1. For example one can take $ G/K $ to be $ PSL_2(\mathbb{C})/SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ or $ SL_2(\mathbb{C}) / SU_2 $ or $ O_{3,1}/O_3 $ or $ SO_{3,1}/SO_3 $ etc... Once you have some model of hyperbolic space $ G/K \cong \mathbb{H}^3 $ then you can take an appropriate discrete closed subgroups $ \Gamma $ of $ G $ ($ \Gamma $ is a lattice or is Zariski dense or is a Kleinian group or large in some other suitable sense) and then the double coset space
$$
\Gamma \backslash G/K
$$
will be a nice hyperbolic manifold, going by names like locally symmetric space, Clifford Klein space form etc... Just wanted to clarify that I already know that Seifert-Weber space is $ \Gamma \backslash G/K $ where $ \Gamma $ is the fundamental group of Seifert-Weber space and $ G/K \cong \mathbb{H}^3 $. Returning to my original question, what I am looking for is a way to realize Seifert-Weber space as $ G/H $ where $ G $ is a Lie group and $ H $ is a closed subgroup.

Comment: No, hyperbolic manifolds of finite volume are **never** homogeneous.

Comment: That is very interesting could you give me a reference for that fact? If I understand you correctly that means that all genus $ g\geq 2 $ surfaces are not homogeneous and all compact hyperbolic 3 manifolds are not homogeneous. Does that also mean all compact 3 manifolds with the $ \mathbb{H}^2 \times \mathbb{R} $ geometry are not homogeneous either? Can we say something like a homogenous manifold always has nonnegative Euler characteristic?

Comment: Yes, every compact homogenous manifold $M$ satisfies $\chi(M)\ge 0$; this was proven by Mostow in "A structure theorem for homogeneous spaces", Geom. Dedicata, 2005. As for the statement about hyperbolic manifolds, I will add an explanation later on.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm trying to better understand your statement "hyperbolic manifolds of finite volume are never homogeneous." For hyperbolic surfaces I see that this follows from the Mostow paper and the fact that hyperbolic surfaces have negative Euler characteristic. But what about odd dimensions? For a compact orientable manifold of odd dimension we always have $ \chi=0 $ so $ \chi(M)\geq 0 $ should be no restriction on compact orientable hyperbolic manifolds of odd dimensions, so how does one conclude that such manifolds can never be homogeneous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Answering your question in a comment: It is known that every compact homogenous manifold $M$ satisfies $\chi(M)\ge 0$, this was proven by Mostow, in

*Mostow, G. D.*, [**A structure theorem for homogeneous spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10711-004-1675-9), Geom. Dedicata 114, 87-102 (2005). [ZBL1086.57024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1086.57024).

2. This theorem is a consequence of a deeper structural results for homogeneous manifolds that Mostow proves in his paper. In section 4, Mostow proves that every connected homogeneous manifold (compact or not) admits an iterated fibration with fibers that are homogeneous manifolds satisfying further properties. Specializing to 3-manifolds $M$, it follows that:

i. either $M$ itself fibers, or

ii. (The exceptional case.) Either $G$ is solvable or is semisimple and in this case $H$ has finitely many connected components. Unfortunately, this exceptional case is poorly explained in the statement of the theorem in the introduction: In this case Mostow should have allowed one more subgroup in his sequence. In Mostow's notation, $k=1$, causing appearance of a subgroup $F_{-1}$ which has to be equal to $\{1\}$, while
$F_0=H$. Then the fibration in the statement of Theorem C reads:
$$
H/F_{-1}=H \to G/F_{-1}=G\to G/H.
$$
Then $G_k=G_1=G$, $\Gamma_k=\Gamma_1=H$ and we are in Mostow's  case 3, where $G=G_1$ is semisimple or solvable and, in the semisimple case, $\Gamma_k$ has finitely many components. Mostow explains this better when he repeats the formulation of Theorem C in the end of section 4 (where this theorem is actually proven).

Case i. If a compact connected 3-manifold  fibers, then either the fiber is a surface and the base is a circle or vice-versa.

(a) If the fiber is a surface, it has to be of nonnegative Euler characteristic (see part 1). Hyperbolic 3-manifolds do not admit such fibrations:

Namely, asphericity of $M$ implies that the fiber $F$ cannot be $S^2, P^2$. The long exact sequences of homotopy groups of a fibration implies  that we have a short exact sequence
$$
1\to \pi_1(F)\to \pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(S^1)= {\mathbb Z}\to 1.
$$
If $F$ is the torus or the Klein bottle then $\pi_1(M)$ would contain a nontrivial normal virtually abelian subgroup which is known to be impossible.

(b) On the other hand, a compact hyperbolic manifold also cannot fiber over a surface $B$ with circular fibers $F$. This again follows from asphericity of $M$ which results in a short exact sequence
$$
1\to \pi_1(F)= {\mathbb Z}\to \pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(B)\to 1.
$$
Then, again we would obtain a normal infinite cyclic subgroup in $\pi_1(M)$, which is impossible.

Thus, compact hyperbolic 3-manifolds cannot admit transitive actions of Lie groups.

With more work, one can relax the compactness assumption in (2) to finiteness of volume and prove a similar theorem in higher dimensions as well.

ii. Consider now the exceptional case. If $G$ is semisimple and $H$ has finitely many components, $\pi_1(M)=\pi_1(G/H)$ is finite. This is impossible for a hyperbolic manifold. Lastly, if $G$ is solvable, so is $H$, hence, $H/H^c$ is solvable too (I am using Mostow's notation where $H^c$ denotes the identity component with respect to the Lie group topology). But then $\pi_1(M)$ is solvable, which is impossible for a hyperbolic manifold of finite volume.

Comment: Does this same line of reasoning show that three manifolds with $ H^2 \times R $ geometry are not homogeneous since again they cannot be realized as a bundle of circles over a sphere/projective plane/torus/klein bottle or as a bundle of a sphere/projective plane/torus/klein bottle over a circle?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Right.

Comment: Would you be willing to submit this same explanation as an answer to my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408960/examples-of-the-thurston-geometries
It's much closer to what I want than the current answers and I would definitely accept it as the answer

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira I have to say, it is unclear to me what the MO question really is. It is possible that it was misformulated (XY problem). But I will add an answer.

Comment: What does Mostow's theorem tell us about homogeneous 2 manifolds which cannot be realized as a 2 dimensional Lie group mod a discrete subgroup (like the sphere, projective plane and Klein bottle)? Can they all be realized as a fibration of a homogenous 1 manifold over another homogeneous 1 manifold ( fibration of the circle over the circle)?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira The only homogeneous connected surfaces are the ones of nonnegative Euler characteristic.

Comment: I was asking not about the Euler characteristic part but about the decomposition of homogeneous manifolds as "iterated fiber bundles with homogeneous fibers where, with exception of one of the fibrations, the fibers of the bundles are diffeomorphic to quotients of connected Lie groups by discrete subgroups" as you stated in your answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408960/examples-of-the-thurston-geometries

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Exactly: Do you know the full list of connected surfaces of nonnegative Euler characteristic? Apart from the sphere and the projective plane, they all fiber with 1-dimensional fibers.

Comment: I think: plane, torus, cylinder, mobius strip, klein bottle, sphere, and projective plane? So what about sphere and projective plane? They aren't the quotient of a connected lie group by a discrete subgroup and they don't fiber in a nice way?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Yes, they are the exceptions: In Mostow's theorem one of the members of the iterated fibration could be like that.

Comment: And if I understand the Mostow paper theorem (C) top of page 99 correctly then (for the case of a homogeneous space which is compact) the at most one exceptional fiber must be homogeneous for a compact adjoint semisimple group (which is SO_3 in the example above)

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira: See the edit: I explained the exceptional case which includes  the case of the projective plane and the sphere.