# Why can't a Lie group act transitively on a finite volume hyperbolic manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

In the comments on

[Is Seifert-Weber space homogeneous for a Lie group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4315238/is-seifert-weber-space-homogeneous-for-a-lie-group)

it is claimed that if $ M $ is a manifold which admits a finite volume hyperbolic metric (constant negative sectional curvature) then there can exist no Lie group $ G $ acting (smoothly) transitively on $ M $. Why is that?

Thoughts on the $ dim(M)=2 $ case (surface): A hyperbolic surface of finite volume must be compact. A compact hyperbolic surface must have negative Euler characteristic. But   *Mostow, G. D.*, [**A structure theorem for homogeneous spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10711-004-1675-9), Geom. Dedicata 114, 87-102 (2005). [ZBL1086.57024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1086.57024) proves that a compact manifold admitting a transitive action by a Lie group must have nonnegative Euler charactersitic $ \chi \geq 0 $. Thus finite volume hyperbolic surfaces are never homogeneous.

The same Mostow paper above is used by Moishe Kohan to prove this result for 3 manifolds [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/409329/387190)

The general proof suggested [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454340/why-cant-a-lie-group-act-transitively-on-a-finite-volume-hyperbolic-manifold) is that you show somehow that a hyperbolic manifold with a transitive $ G $ action must be simply connected and then a simply connected hyperbolic manifold is $ \mathbb{H}^n $ and so does not have finite volume.

The crux of the proof then is to show that a hyperbolic manifold with a transitive $ G $ action must be simply connected.

Comment: For actions by isometries this is easy, by applying the fact that the isometry group is finite. But I suppose you are interested even in actions by homeomorphisms?

Comment: @LeeMosher yes that's right I'm interested even in homeomorphisms.

Comment: the isometry group of a finite volume hyperbolic space is always finite, isn't the group of conformal bijections even finite?

Comment: In 2 dimensions, those two groups coincide, by the generalized Riemann mapping theorem. In higher dimensions... I don't know.